# Why/When are some rejected mails not listed in rspamd history

Tags: postfix, milter, rspamd

I am seeing mails which are greylisted/rejected by rspamd according to the postfix log which are not shown in rspamd's GUI history.

I have two questions:
Which are the general cases when mails are not listed in the history?
Do you have an idea why this might happen in this case?

Please tell me if I need to provide more information.

Here is the postfix log for one of these messages which does not show up.
Greylisting:

```
 Aug 12 19:15:52 gtwy01 postfix/smtpd[1587]: connect from smtp.example.com[aa.bb.cc.dd]
 Aug 12 19:15:53 gtwy01 postfix/smtpd[1587]: 12BGF100AB: client=smtp.example.com[aa.bb.cc.dd]
 Aug 12 19:15:54 gtwy01 postfix/cleanup[1578]: 12BGF100AB: milter-reject: END-OF-MESSAGE from smtp.example.com[aa.bb.cc.dd]: 4.7.1 Try again later; from=<sender@example.com> to=<receiver@domain.com> proto=ESMTP helo=<smtp.example.com>
 Aug 12 19:15:54 gtwy01 postfix/smtpd[1587]: disconnect from smtp.example.com[aa.bb.cc.dd] ehlo=2 starttls=1 mail=1 rcpt=1 data=0/1 quit=1 commands=6/7
```

Reject:

```
 Aug 12 19:15:54 gtwy02 postfix/smtpd[12772]: connect from smtp.example.com[aa.bb.cc.dd]
 Aug 12 19:15:54 gtwy02 postfix/smtpd[12772]: 2A321200EF: client=smtp.example.com[aa.bb.cc.dd]
 Aug 12 19:15:54 gtwy02 postfix/cleanup[12773]: 2A321200EF: milter-reject: END-OF-MESSAGE from smtp.example.com[aa.bb.cc.dd]: 5.7.1 Spam message rejected; from=<sender@example.com> to=<receiver@domain.com> proto=ESMTP helo=<smtp.example.com>
 Aug 12 19:15:54 gtwy02 postfix/smtpd[12772]: disconnect from smtp.example.com[aa.bb.cc.dd] ehlo=2 starttls=1 mail=1 rcpt=1 data=0/1 quit=1 commands=6/7
```

s

Comment: A long time ago, but have you found out an answer? I have the exact issue

Comment: No, I haven't. I'm not actively working with postfix atm but I am still curious why this happens.